# Is my clutch worn out?

Tags: honda, clutch, clutch-cylinder, clutch-plate, city

I have Honda City i-detch 2014 India version.

Symptoms:

1. low pickup
2. In third gear high RPM but very less pickup
3. Gear shifting little hard
4. Clutch paddle high than normal.

I took my car to showroom and they said this are clutch worn symptoms. (they checked cylinder bleeding too)

Today I got my local mechanic to open the clutch and my clutch look like below, I can see mesh on the clutch however there are little wear on side.

**The question is:**

1. Is my clutch really worn or there is some other issue?
2. Why only edges are worn?

**Flywheel side:**

[image]

**Other side:**

[image]

[image]

Added flywheel image

Answer (score 1):

While the friction disk does not look worn out, there's more to a clutch than just the friction disk. You are also showing the pressure plate, which you can see wear on. The part you haven't shown is the flywheel, which is the other part. We cannot see if there are heat cracks or other signs of wear. The part which you cannot show is whether the springs are shot in the pressure plate. If they are, you'd lose grip in the clutch and you just cannot show that in a picture.

Normally there are a couple of things which you can tell if a clutch is going or has gone bad. The easiest way to tell is if you put the car in a higher gear than would be normal for the speed of the vehicle. Then release the clutch and try to accelerate. If the car accelerates at a normal speed (probably very slowly) and the engine speeds up accordingly (slowly), then the clutch is holding just fine. If the engine speeds up and the car doesn't, then the clutch is slipping and should be looked at. (Maybe this is what you were trying to explain in #2 of the first section, but this is unclear to me.)

Comment: Can u tell me where the pressure plate is worn out?? I don't have much knowledge of this ;)

Comment: @rishiwankhade - I was just saying it *shows wear*, not that it's worn out. I couldn't tell you for sure that it is worn out. You can see striations on the plate which shows wear, but other than that, there's no blueing (which would show over heating) or heat cracks, so wear is as would be expected. Another way to tell if it needs to be replaced is if you can run your finger nail across it and it catches on the striations. If it's glazed it may be time for replacement as well. It doesn't *look* worn out from the images, but it does look used.

Comment: Something else to consider is, since you have the clutch out you should go ahead and replace it anyway. No time like the present and you've already paid for the removal of the old one. The cost of a new clutch is minimal. Ensure you either replace the flywheel or get it resurfaced. You'll know for sure you have a good clutch in there then.